# finding variables in the global object - javascript

Tags: javascript

with only

```
var test = 'test message';
console.log(this);
```

in the console (in Chrome), where in that object would I find the test variable?

if I had this.test = 'test message' instead of var test, I'd see it in a test key in the window object, but not when I use the latter

Comment: `console.log(test === this.test === window.test)`

Comment: IF you're defining variable in the Global context in Browser, its attached to the Window object. You can access it `window.test` or `this.test`

Comment: If you mean "where does `test` show up in the console's visual representation of the `window` object", that depends entirely on your environment.

Comment: if I had this.test = 'test message' instead of var test, I'd see it in a test key in the window object in Chrome, but not when I use the latter

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the context of `this` object. I think this [MDN Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) can help you understanding `this` better.
Coming to your question, in the provided snippet the context of `this` is `window`. Hence you can directly access `test` by `this.test`. If the context of `this` changes then it won't be available.

```
var test = 'test message';
console.log(this.test); // Try in browser console.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Unable to reproduce**

Click on the arrow to the left of the logged `this` object (which is `window`). Scroll down to `stylemedia` in the first alphabetic list of properties presented by Chrome. The definition of `test` follows, immediately before `toolbar`.

Avoid getting confused by scrolling down to the second alphabetic list of properties and not seeing it between `SyntaxError` and `TaskAttributionTiming` properties. It's not in the second section of properties.

If this solves the issue, *please consider deleting the question without accepting any answers*